# CSS Grid with separators items inside grid having different width and height than grid items

Tags: css, css-grid

I am building a overview of entries which I want to look like this:

[image: How it should look like]

I am planning to use CSS grid layout. The grid layout will take advantage of the available width and use the space which is unused.

I have pretty much all I need already like I want it, however, with the `grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` (to make sure every item is the same height although they might have different heights due to multiline titles or other effects too complex for this example) my **.separator** items get a lot more space than their actual height. Any ideas how to solve this issue?

I attached full example code here:

```css
* {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.grid {
  --grid-item-width: 116px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--grid-item-width), 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}
  
.separator {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;

  background-color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: stretch;

  background-color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 30px;
}
    
.item img {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="separator">.separator</div>
  <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
  <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
  <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
  <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
  <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
  <div class="separator">.separator</div>
  <div class="item">.item</div>
  <div class="item">.item</div>
  <div class="item">.item</div>
  <div class="item">.item</div>
  <div class="item">.item</div>
  <div class="item">.item</div>
  <div class="item">.item</div>
  <div class="item">.item</div>
  <div class="item">.item</div>
  <div class="item">.item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Frankly I'd be using separate containers for each grouping since you're probably adding the seperators programatically then you can probably leverage `subgrid`

Comment: @Paulie_D The problem about this variant is that the sizing of the items within one grid are not reliant on those items in another grid.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is `grid-auto-rows: max-content`. Run the code snippet below.

```css
* {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.grid {
  --grid-item-width: 116px;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--grid-item-width), 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: max-content;
  gap: 20px;
}
  
.separator {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;

  background-color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: stretch;

  background-color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 30px;
}
    
.item img {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="separator">.separator</div>
  <div class="item"><img>Short item</div>
  <div class="item"><img>Short item</div>
  <div class="item"><img>Long item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
  <div class="separator">.separator</div>
  <div class="item">Even longer item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </div>
  <div class="item">Short item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and your answer. I just included it into my productive code and noticed, whenever a grid item moves to a new row it is not the same size as the previous ones anymore...

Answer (score 1):

What is a bit disturbing is the fact that some items have images and
others do not. Will you have more text inside of them?

If this content is generated with some backend logic, then you could
replace the missing `<img>` tag by a square empty `<div>`, in order to
fill the missing space, making its height vary with the width of the
item.

This is the same trick as how to make `<iframe>` videos keep the
same ratio while keeping them elastic. The idea is to use a top padding
with the `%` unit. It seems unlogical, but this value is in percentage
of the width and not the height. So if you set a top padding to 100%
then you'll get the same height as its width (of course, if the div is
empty). For videos, you set the container `<div>` to position relative
and then set the child `<iframe>` to position absolute and put top,
bottom, right and left to 0, so that the iframe fills the container.

Here, I just wrapped your grid in a resizeable container so that we
can resize it and see what happens.

I personally replaced your `px` values into `em`, just because I find
it quite important to make it fully elastic to the font size,
that one sets on the `<html>` or `<body>` tag and which is inherited
on all descendants. This way, you can reduce or increase the size
of a part of the page and all the paddings, margins, radius, etc will
be changed to look good with the font size.

```css
html {
  /*
  Don't set font with * { } because this will affect
  all HTML tags, including forms, which should usually
  stay a system/user setting. Set it on the html or
  body tag and it will be inherited on usual HTML tags.
  Play with this codepen: https://codepen.io/patacra/pen/LYJewNM

  Default browser font size is 16px. This will be
  reduced on the grid container when it gets narrow.
  Line height without unit → relative to font size.
  */
  font: 16px/1.6 Verdana;
}

:root {
  --item-bg-color: #CCC;
  --item-border-radius: .5em;
  --grid-gap: 1.2em;
}

/* For the demo, make the container div resizeable horizontally. */
.resizeable {
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid silver;
  /* Trick to have margins of child element working and
     not going out of the parent container. I can't set
     the padding to var(--grid-gap) because it is in em
     unit and I want to the be the same as the grid gap,
     which is changed later with the @container query
     affecting the font size. */
  padding: 0.0001px;
  /* Enable @container queries on this element and name it. */
  container-type: inline-size;
  container-name: resizeable;
}

/* Display a blinking "resize me" message at the bottom right. */
.resizeable::after {
  content: "resize me →";
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: .8em;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 1em;
  animation: blink 3s linear infinite;
}
/* The blink animation keyframes. */
@keyframes blink {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

.grid {
  --grid-item-width: 80px; /* Reduced for the Stackoverflow answer. */

  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--grid-item-width), 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  gap: var(--grid-gap);
  margin: var(--grid-gap); /* Instead of padding on parent. */
}
  
.separator {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  padding: .2em .8em;
  background-color: var(--item-bg-color);
  border-radius: var(--item-border-radius);

  /*
  I'm septic on these two rules. What happens if the
  text of the separator is on several lines? I would
  remove both and increase the vertical padding
  if needed. Leave the height auto adjust to its content.
  */
  /* height: 1.6em; */
  /* vertical-align: middle; */
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: stretch;

  background-color: var(--item-bg-color);
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: var(--item-border-radius);
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 1.8; /* Don't use any unit → will stay elastic. */
}

.item img {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.square-spacer {
  height: 0;
  padding: 100% 0 0 0; /* Top padding = 100% of element width. */
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 0px,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, .5) 10px,
    transparent 10px,
    transparent 20px
  );
}

/* Based on the width of <div class="resizable"> */
@container resizeable (max-width: 400px) {
  /*
  Just for the demo, reduce font size of all the grid.
  One would do that with a media query on the screen size
  and not on the resizeable container. But it's just to
  show that one can change things only for the grid,
  indepedently of the rest of the page.
  */
  .grid {
    font-size: .6em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="resizeable">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="separator">.separator</div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/160/160" alt="image 1">.item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/160/160" alt="image 2">.item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/160/160" alt="image 3">.item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/160/160" alt="image 4">.item
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/160/160" alt="image 5">.item
    </div>
    <div class="separator">.separator</div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square-spacer"></div>.item</div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square-spacer"></div>.item</div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square-spacer"></div>.item</div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square-spacer"></div>.item</div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square-spacer"></div>.item</div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square-spacer"></div>.item</div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square-spacer"></div>.item</div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square-spacer"></div>.item</div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square-spacer"></div>.item</div>
    <div class="item"><div class="square-spacer"></div>.item</div>
  </div>
<div>
```

Comment: I really like the effort you put into this answer! Also I definitely agree with the improvements you did to my code, it was rather a quick example than my actual code, so what you are saying about heights and sizes is correct. 

However unfortunately, I don't have images in every item and those without usually have more text. So I don't know why but what you coded has the same effect as just removing `grid-auto-rows` from my example and items in different rows will result in different heights, if they have different contents. I want only `.separator` to have a different height.

Comment: Thanks @TimNikischin! With pleasure. Well, I must admit I don’t really see how to solve your problem without JS. If the height of your items is based on the tallest, I don’t really see how it could be solved with pure CSS as I imagine the grid height is determined by the tallest item of one row, only. You could set a min-height or a fixed height to your items and trim long texts or reduce the font size of the items with a lot of characters. This could be done with some CSS classes generated by the backend, for each item. I hope you’ll find a neat solution!

Answer (score 0):

I propose to you to structure your html a little bit differently your html, i removed the `grid` class on the top div and i added a div to wrap all your `.items`, and i putted on this div the `grid` class.

```css
* {
  font-family: Verdana;
}

.grid {
  --grid-item-width: 116px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--grid-item-width), 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
  
.separator {
  padding: 4px 10px;
  height: 22px;
  line-height: 22px;
  background-color: #CCC;
  border-radius: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: stretch;

  background-color: #CCC;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 30px;
}
    
.item img {
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="separator">.separator</div>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
      <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
      <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
      <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
      <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
    </div>
    <div class="separator">.separator</div>
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
      <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
      <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
      <div class="item"><img>.item</div>
      <div class="item"><img>.item</div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem about this variant is that the sizing of the items within the grid are not reliant on those items in another grid.